# GridLayouts not becoming Scrollable

Tags: xml, android-layout

I am trying to make the Gridlayout Scrollable but I am failed in doing so. The problem is that it automatically adjusting it inside the view.

My XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="134dp"
            android:id="@+id/logo_dash"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Home"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo_dash"

            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
    <GridLayout

        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:columnCount="1"

        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20sp"
            app:cardElevation="32dp">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/g_img"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20sp"
            app:cardElevation="32dp">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/g_img"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20sp"
            app:cardElevation="32dp">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/g_img"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20sp"
            app:cardElevation="32dp">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/g_img"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20sp"
            app:cardElevation="32dp">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/g_img"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is my xml code in which i used scrollview and then linear layout as child then two childs inside linear layout Relative Layout and Grid Layout.

[image: I want this to make scrollable]

Comment: **mainactivity.kt**       [link](https://pastebin.com/vX023T7X)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can achieve this.

1. Use **hardcoded** size for GridLayout. Like set height for ex. 400dp or anything. That way it'll have that size and scroll inside that area of height.
2. Use **NestedScrollView** instead of **ScrollView**. *ScrollView doesn't work properly with views that are also scrollable*, here Gridlayout is already scrollable, but when you put it inside scrollview it stopped working properly.

Here is an example of NestedScrollView with GridLayout (Credit - [Mersad Esalati](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52252479/9932194) )

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:rowCount="4">
    
                <!-- fill your grid -->
    
            </GridLayout>
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```